# push_back() and emplace_back() behind the scenes

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std, move-semantics

I'm currently learning C++ on my own, and I am curious about how `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` work under the hood. I've always assumed that `emplace_back()` is faster when you are trying to construct and push a large object to the back of a container, like a vector.

Let's suppose I have a `Student` object that I want to append to the back of a vector of Students.

```
struct Student {
   string name;
   int student_ID;
   double GPA;
   string favorite_food;
   string favorite_prof;
   int hours_slept;
   int birthyear;
   Student(string name_in, int ID_in, double GPA_in, string food_in, 
           string prof_in, int sleep_in, int birthyear_in) :
           /* initialize member variables */ { }
};
```

Suppose I call `push_back()` and push a `Student` object to the end of a vector:

```
vector<Student> vec;
vec.push_back(Student("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997));
```

My understanding here is that `push_back` creates an instance of the `Student` object outside of the vector and then moves it to the back of the vector.

Diagram: [image: https://ibb.co/hV6Jho]

I can also emplace instead of push:

```
vector<Student> vec;
vec.emplace_back("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997);
```

My understanding here is that the Student object is constructed at the very back of the vector so that no moving is required.

Diagram: [image]

Thus, it would make sense that emplacing would be faster, especially if many Student objects are added. However, when I timed these two versions of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(Student("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997));
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    vec.emplace_back("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997);
}
```

I expected the latter to be faster, since the large Student object wouldn't have to be moved. Oddly enough, the `emplace_back` version ended up being slower (across multiple attempts). I also tried inserting 10000000 Student objects, where the constructor takes in references and the arguments in `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` are stored in variables. This also didn't work, as emplace was still slower.

I've checked to make sure that I'm inserting the same number of objects in both cases. The time difference isn't too large, but emplacing ended up slower by a few seconds.

Is there something wrong with my understanding of how `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` work? Thank you very much for your time!

Here's the code, as requested. I'm using the g++ compiler.

Push back:

```
struct Student {
   string name;
   int student_ID;
   double GPA;
   string favorite_food;
   string favorite_prof;
   int hours_slept;
   int birthyear;
   Student(string name_in, int ID_in, double GPA_in, string food_in, 
           string prof_in, int sleep_in, int birthyear_in) :
           name(name_in), student_ID(ID_in), GPA(GPA_in), 
           favorite_food(food_in), favorite_prof(prof_in),
           hours_slept(sleep_in), birthyear(birthyear_in) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<Student> vec;
    vec.reserve(10000000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) 
         vec.push_back(Student("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997));
    return 0;
}
```

Emplace back:

```
struct Student {
   string name;
   int student_ID;
   double GPA;
   string favorite_food;
   string favorite_prof;
   int hours_slept;
   int birthyear;
   Student(string name_in, int ID_in, double GPA_in, string food_in, 
           string prof_in, int sleep_in, int birthyear_in) :
           name(name_in), student_ID(ID_in), GPA(GPA_in), 
           favorite_food(food_in), favorite_prof(prof_in),
           hours_slept(sleep_in), birthyear(birthyear_in) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<Student> vec;
    vec.reserve(10000000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) 
         vec.emplace_back("Bob", 123456, 3.89, "pizza", "Smith", 7, 1997);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler? Compilation options? Compilable code?

Comment: One difference is that the code has to pass 7 parameters to `emplace_back`, but only one to `push_back`.

Comment: @KillzoneKid push_back can take a right-reference and move, but it is moving the temporary constructed object.

Comment: Unless you used reserve() on your vector, for large counts the costs of moving all the existing elements each time your vector grows will swamp the difference in cost of insertion, I would think!

Comment: @GemTaylor So does push_back create a temporary constructed object and move it to the back of the vector? Also, I added the reserve() line and the times seem more reasonable. Thank you!

Comment: In the push_back case, the optimizer might recognize that the temporary Student object is loop invariant, so it could be hoisted out of the loop, constructing it just once, and copying it over and over into the vector.  In the emplace_back case, you have to construct a new one each time, which may involve creating `std::strings` from the string literals each time.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Would randomly generating Student objects with different member variable values fix this?

Comment: @azhu5355 You need to post the compiler options you used, not just the compiler name.  If you are timing an unoptimized build, the timings you're reporting are meaningless.

Comment: @azhu5355 In `vec.push_back(Student("Bob"...`  `Student()` creates a temporary object, and push_back() moves it, if there is a useful move operator. For most "large" objects, their content is something that can be usefully moved (eg std::string or nested containers), and the cost compared to emplace is marginal. I think @Adrian might be onto something as well. If the object can't be moved, then it could be constructed just once and some processing saved.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Yes, I think that might be it. I'm using C++11, and the C++11 results look a lot like mine.

Comment: @GemTaylor So if an object can be usefully moved, even if it is large, emplace doesn't give too big of an advantage? Do you have an example where the difference between pushing and emplacing is large? Most of the examples I'm testing have rather similar times for both push and emplace. Thanks!

Comment: @KillzoneKid These unoptimized benchmark results are utterly meaningless.

Comment: @azhu5355 If your object has very many (1KB+) small members, then move is not useful. If the constructor for the object only takes a few parameters, and the rest calculated,then emplace might be faster. But most object models for larger objects are basically pimpl, and move of a pimpl is trivial. Trying to think of an example, but it isn't real world, perhaps your object caches the next 1000 random numbers from some input seed, and holds them in a c array int[1000]. Move can't do anything with that, but you should be pointing to it with unique_ptr<int[]>, and move of the pointer is trivial.

Comment: @azhu5355  Simply respect your effort to write a such a well organised question.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Google Benchmark varies the amount of iterations it uses, so not reseting the vector on each loop is a really bad idea. Instead, you should put the code in the loop and use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` or `benchmark::ClobberMemory` (when appropriate) to prevent the compiler from optimizing the variable away. Like so: http://quick-bench.com/5tQMkMwC5-j4nmUYSsqcmWeNEPs (note that optimizations are **on**)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is due to the complexity of `std::string`. There are a couple things interacting here:

- The Small String Optimization (SSO)
- In the `push_back` version, the compiler is able to determine the length of the string at compile-time, whereas the compiler was unable to do so for the `emplace_back` version. Thus, the `emplace_back` call requires calls to `strlen`. Furthermore, since the compiler doesn't know the length of the string literal, it has to emit code for both the SSO and non-SSO cases (see Jason Turner's ["Initializer Lists Are Broken, Let's Fix Them"](https://youtu.be/sSlmmZMFsXQ); it's a long talk, but he follows the problem of inserting strings into a vector throughout it)

Consider this simpler type:

```
struct type {
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
  std::string c;

  type(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c)
    : a{a}
    , b{b}
    , c{c}
  {}
};
```

Note how the constructor *copies* `a`, `b`, and `c`.

[Testing this against a baseline of just allocating memory](http://quick-bench.com/GI52ylDcmLX9ltFZ1CpFdVC44T4), we can see that `push_back` outperforms `emplace_back`:

[image]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/GI52ylDcmLX9ltFZ1CpFdVC44T4)</sup>

Because the strings in your example all fit inside the SSO buffer, copying is just as cheap as moving in this case. Thus, the constructor is perfectly efficient, and the improvements from `emplace_back` have a smaller effect.

Also, if we search [the assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/5sW5th) for both a call to `push_back` and a call to `emplace_back`:

```
// push_back call
void foo(std::vector<type>& vec) {
    vec.push_back({"Bob", "pizza", "Smith"});
}
```

```
// emplace_back call
void foo(std::vector<type>& vec) {
    vec.emplace_back("Bob", "pizza", "Smith");
}
```

(Assembly not copied here. It's massive. `std::string` is complicated)

We can see that `emplace_back` has calls to `strlen`, whereas `push_back` does not. Since the distance between the string literal and the `std::string` being constructed is increased, the compiler was unable to optimize out the call to `strlen`.

Explicitly calling the `std::string` constructor would remove the calls to `strlen`, but would no longer construct them in place, so that doesn't work to speed up `emplace_back`.

All this said, [if we leave the SSO by using long enough strings](http://quick-bench.com/iqvwUCZPgLfomXWj8bSsn-S8u3s), the allocation cost completely drowns out these details, so both `emplace_back` and `push_back` have the same performance:

[image]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/iqvwUCZPgLfomXWj8bSsn-S8u3s)</sup>

---

If you fix the constructor of `type` to move its arguments, `emplace_back` becomes faster in all cases.

```
struct type {
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
  std::string c;

  type(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c)
    : a{std::move(a)}
    , b{std::move(b)}
    , c{std::move(c)}
  {}
};
```

[SSO case](http://quick-bench.com/hm5NsZ5LiJxdMvEr-ZlxjdQlh7U)

[image]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/hm5NsZ5LiJxdMvEr-ZlxjdQlh7U)</sup>

[Long case](http://quick-bench.com/ItCj5-YmLWM0ZGwTBvTmPuYCCzo)

[image]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/ItCj5-YmLWM0ZGwTBvTmPuYCCzo)</sup>

However, the SSO `push_back` case slowed down; the compiler seems to emit extra copies.

The [optimal version of perfect forwarding](http://quick-bench.com/cYYcWFxfOZ_JocAwWYlJlGyduY4) does not suffer from this drawback (note the scale change on the vertical axis):

```
struct type {
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
  std::string c;

  template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
  type(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c)
    : a{std::forward<A>(a)}
    , b{std::forward<B>(b)}
    , c{std::forward<C>(c)}
  {}
};
```

[image]

<sup>[Click on image for quick-bench link](http://quick-bench.com/cYYcWFxfOZ_JocAwWYlJlGyduY4)</sup>

Comment: This is a neat answer, but that observation that `emplace_back` is making `strlen` calls is super interesting.

Comment: @Cornstalks More like the `emplace_back` prevents the compiler from optimizing out the `strlen`, but yeah

Comment: You've inspired me to open [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51219755/1287251) regarding `emplace_back` and `strlen`.