# Why does emplace_back("Hello") call strlen?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

[Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219195/1287251) on another question made an observation that I find very interesting but can't quite explain. Consider the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("Hello, world!");  // Doesn't call strlen.
v.emplace_back("Hello, world!");  // Calls strlen.
```

If you look at the assembly, [`emplace_back` generates a call to `strlen`](https://godbolt.org/g/pTqBC4), whereas [`push_back` does not](https://godbolt.org/g/vCACqj) (tested in gcc 8.1 and clang 6.0 using `-Ofast`).

Why is this happening? Why can't `emplace_back` optimize out the `strlen` call here? My initial thought was that `push_back` is implicitly creating the `std::string` *before* the function call (so the `std::string` constructor is directly passed the string literal, which is optimally handled), whereas `emplace_back` creates the `std::string` *after* the function call (so the `std::string` constructor is *forwarded* the string literal, which I presumed had decayed from a `const char [N]` to a `const char *`, thus requiring a `strlen` call).

But [`emplace_back` takes a `T&&` parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), and [my tests show that the string literal shouldn't be decaying to a pointer here](https://godbolt.org/g/usXTS2). Clearly I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Have you noticed that the `strlen()` call only occurs if the vector needs to be resized?  In the normal case where `size() < capacity()`, there is no call to `strlen()`.  So performance wise this makes no difference because only the slow path has the `strlen()` call, and it's slow for lots of other reasons anyway.

Comment: So your question is really "why don't `gcc 8.1` optimize as I want it to?"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Not just GCC. The exact same thing happens with clang and libc++. And I'm asking because I'm curious.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Interesting! I had not noticed that.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Well then I think the next thing you should do is read the assembly code and figure out what the compiler is doing when it calls `strlen()`.

Comment: Play with other optimization settings (GCC has many of them). You might have surprises.

Comment: Not all `const char [N]`s are string literals.

Comment: And you can't assume that a `const char [N]` will not have a `'\0'` *before* the end.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Because it informs how one might go about writing optimal code.

Comment: Not sure of that. You need to benchmark. `strlen` can be really quick. And with extra optimization flags, it could be computed at compile-time. **Leave micro-optimizations to the compiler** (unless you are sure that a small piece of code is performance-critical, and you care about that. Then you benchmark and rewrite that piece of code. Most of the time your optimization efforts won't pay out. Usually developer time is more costly than computer time)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The OP asked an interesting question. While it's true that one usually need not care too much about micro-optimizations, I'm sure the OP already knows that and is simply asking out of intellectual curiosity.

Comment: But optimizations *are* compiler specific. The reason why GCC 8 does not optimize enough is not exactly the reason why Clang 6 does not optimize enough (even if they could be similar). My guess is that it is weird case not though of by compiler writers. You cannot expect a compiler to make all the optimizations you want to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `strlen` call is in the out-of-line function body for the slow path; that function body must be valid for all arguments of type `const char (&)[42]` (in your godbolt example), including arguments that did not originate from a string literal of 41 characters with no embedded nulls.

The fast path is inlined into `foo`, and it does compute the length at compile time.